# div inside div is not obeying margin and hiding the child

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

[image: Here the buttons do not even appear][image: Look at the save and view more]I have a page where I display a series of jobs inside divs. One parent div contain two sub divs. One for text description which occupies 80% of the container and the other one occupies 20% of the container. The right one has the company's picture and two buttons in-line at the bottom for save and view more. However, in one div the buttons are touching the line of the container and in the 2nd one it is moving higher. Also, for the first sub div containing description, I want to have a fixed size text and any other overflow should be like .....

However, it is not happening and in one  div, the text covers the buttons which do not show up.
Also, whenever I click on the save, it scrolls to the top :((

How do I properly format it please? Thank you

Here is my code snippet

```css
.internship_posting {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #00468c;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.internship_desc p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: calc(70%);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.content_for_right {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20%;
}

.content_for_right a.save {
  color: #00000030;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.heart i.fa-heart {
  color: #f44336;
}

.heart {
  animation: heart 0.5s linear;
}

div a.btn:hover {
  color: rgb(93, 129, 177)
}

div a.btn:active {
  background-color: rgb(99, 175, 226);
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

@keyframes heart {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.7);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  41% {
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
}


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" style="width: 100%;">
      <h2 style="margin-top: 20px; color: #00468c; text-align: 
      center;">Showing internships for {{ industry_type.industry_name }}</h2>
          {% for internship, recruiter in posts %}
              <div class="internship_posting">
              <img style="float:right" src="{{ recruiter.company_picture.url 
              }}" width="80" height=auto alt="">
              <div style="padding:20px; overflow:hidden; width: 80%;">
              <h4 style="color: black;"><strong>{{internship.internship_title 
              }} 
              <p><span style="color: black;">Start Date: </span>{{ 
              internship.start_date }} <span style="color: 
              black;">&nbsp;&nbsp;End Date: </span>{{ internship.end_date } 
              </p>
              <div class="internship_desc;">
                 <p>{{ internship.internship_desc | safe}}</p>
              </div>  
             </div>

             <div class="content_for_right">
                <a href="#" class="save" style="display: inline-block;">
                  <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                <a style= "color:white; background-color:#23c0e9;" class="btn 
                button" href="{% url 'view_details' internship.id %}"> 
                <strong>View More>></strong></a>
              </div>
            </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: Your example does not seem to reproduce the problem you describe. Please provide a working example of your problem.

Comment: @ChrisG check it

Comment: The example code provided does not match the picture. Please provide a working example of your problem.

Comment: @ChrisG, but this is the code :/

Comment: This looks some sort of js-template. Post the generated code with some cards inside the snipped.

Comment: @cloned, the displayed styles have been coded from scratch. check the code

Comment: @Alpha The fact remains that you do not have a working example that exhibits the issue you describe.  Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ChrisG :/. It's a Django project but this is the html part. Can't you try to help by looking at the styles I have for my div classes? This is causing the issues :(

Comment: If you provide a working example of your problem, I'd be happy to help.